# Initialize C array with blob file

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, linker, blob

I write program in C in Visual Studio 2008. I want to have array initialized from binary file. But i don't want to have binary file alongside with .exe file. So I must embed binary file into my .exe. I searched over Google. Most of answers advice me to use "Resources" in VS. But I don't know OOP and I don't need such complicated solution.
I use "Project->Options->Linker->Input->Raw binary image" in IAR EW for the same purpose. And it match excellent for this task.
How to do it in VS?

Comment: Windows way is using resources. BTW, you don't need OOP for this :) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4221/Adding-and-extracting-binary-resources

Comment: And how about Linux? Can I make my program crossplatform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a simple script in your favorite scripting language and process the binary file into a a comma-delimited set of values before the compilation (there are probably free tools available online as well). Embed this set of values into your source C file to statically initialize an array. E.g., the result can be something like `char data[] = {0x12, 0xAB, 0xC0, ... };` - do with this data whatever you want in your source code.

Comment: I know this solution. But my binary file is ~0,5 KB large. I want to freely modify it without need to convert. And I don't want to have such "magic" initialization.

Comment: You can automate this process to be a pre-processor step that runs before compilation. Changes will be automatically projected into your source code when you change the binary and rebuild the project.